# Font looks different on same sytem, same browser, different resolutions

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have PC with Windows 7 and Firefox 14 and same system and browser on my laptop, font looks totally different I can't figure out why, Is it possible that resolution has something to do with it?

Resolution on my PC is 1920x1080 and on my laptop it is 1280x720, page is fixed width and scales correctly. On some parts of page text look like it has different distance between letters on laptop.

I'm using standard font families on whole site: `Century Gothic, sans-serif;` and it is ok on my PC but on my laptop it looks more like Arial.

I'm suspecting on resolution but maybe I'm wrong, is there something else that can cause this behaviour?

Comment: I'm not sure what the standard fonts are, but if Century Gothic is not installed on the laptop, it will default to the sans-serif font, which would be Arial or something that looks quite like Arial, such as MS Sans Serif.

Comment: Also, if you really want the results to be identical on the two machines, check if they have the same font smoothing settings, the same DPI values etc. And the font preferences of the Firefoxes, like "minimum font size".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to enclose it in quotes. `font-family: "Century Gothic", sans-serif;`. It's likely that one machine is rendering the default `sans-serif` font.

It could also be that Century Gothic is not installed on your laptop.

Comment: I don't know why did I think that Century Gothic come installed with Windows, I will try to change it to something else that I'm sure it's installed.